# Textarea split text into rows and cols

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

Hi I am working over some textarea which needs to have this kind of functionality: I get in config max lines number and max characters per line number. But I can't think of any algorithm for splitting text into this config values. It would be easy but I have to take into considaration that user can break text by himself and this should be included... Can anyone help me with that?

Please also note that I am not using monospaced font.

I have wrote some code which presents what I am trying to achieve:

```
splitIntoLines:function (str, lines, maxCharactersPerLine) {
var strLen = str.length,
    counter = maxCharactersPerLine,
    newStr = '';

if (str.length > 0) {
  for (var i = 0; i < strLen; i++) {
    newStr += str[i];
    counter -= 1;

    if (str[i] === '\n' || str[i] === '\r\n' || counter < 0) {
      counter = maxCharactersPerLine;
    }

    if (counter === 0 && this.countLines(newStr) < lines) {
      newStr += this.newLine;
    }
  }
}

if(newStr.length > this.maxChars){
  newStr = newStr.substring(0, this.maxChars)
}


return newStr;

}
```

This function is called every keyUp event. But I think that it isn't best way and it has some bugs.

Comment: What end-result are you expecting, and what HTML are you starting with?

Answer (score 1):

Simple.. while giving textarea define rows and cols properties to that textarea like

```
<textarea rows="10" cols="30"></textarea>
```

Comment: This works when font is monospace but I am using Arial which isn't

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, but I'm having trouble understanding the question at all. Can I ask: what do you think was asked?

Comment: He need to seperate the text as per config values

Comment: "I get in config max lines number and max characters per line number" this will simply drawn from this solution thats why I have given this solution

Comment: Yes but for me this solution wont work since I don't use monospaced font

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var max_line = 4, max_char = 10;
        $('#addAccordion').click(function (event) {
            var lines = $('#cmt_content').val().split('\n');
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                if (lines[i].length > max_char) {
                    alert('character length is more than specified');

                }
            }
            if (lines.length > max_line) {
                alert('new line is not allowed');

            }
        })
    });

</script>
<div>
    <textarea id="cmt_content" rows="10" cols="60"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input id="addAccordion" type="button" value="ADD COMMENT" />
</div>
```